# Data loader read data from CSV to Salesforce contact (using UPSERT)

Tags: data-loader

Is it possible to use data loader command line to read data from a CSV file and UPSERT into Salesforce contact by a schedule time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  The data loader doesn't have a built in scheduler so you'd need to use the appropriate tool for your operating system (cron, windows scheduler) to start it up. You'll also need to provide the Salesforce record id or an external id field in the file so that the contact records in the file can be matched against those already present in Salesforce.

You might want to take a look at Jitterbit, as this has built in scheduling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using JitterBit Data loader.
If you want to know how to schedule ? Then use the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaTKzUmLATo